# Making a div to display as none

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which makes a div to display as none when anywhere outside the div is clicked. But my problem is I also want the link which makes the div to display block to also close the div if the div is displayed as block so I ran this code:

```
function show_div(x){
    var box = document.getElementById(x);
    if(box.style.display=='block'){
        box.style.display='none';
    } else {
        box.style.display='block';
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
            if(event.target != box && event.target.parentNode != box){
                box.style.display='none';
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But the link does not close the div.  if I run it like this:

```
function show_div(x){
    var box = document.getElementById(x);
    if(box.style.display=='block'){
        box.style.display='none';
    } else {
        box.style.display='block';
    }
}
```

The link opens and closes the div, But I also want a click anywhere outside the div to close the div also. Please do anyone have a better Idea on how I can achieve this? Here is my HTML:

```
<a onclick="show_div('divd')" href="javascript:;">click</a>
<div id="divd">this is the div</div>
```

Comment: You've used the jQuery tag, and there's no jQuery here. Are you accepting jQuery answers?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/2gyg5m85/1/

Use css.
Put it in a wrapper
then put another div at the bottom-inside of the wrapper that fills the entire screen but is not visible. but if clicked also hides the div.

Comment: @Drew... My bad, I was in a hurry typing the question. If you have a jQuery solution I am OK with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Portal_Zii said, you'll probably need a wrapper/container for your div to hide it, but this example should give you a basic idea.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $div = $("#divd");

  $("a").on("click", function() {
    $div.toggle(); // this is to toggle div visibilty
  });

  $div.on("click", function(e) {
    // prevent div from closing when clicking inside
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });

  $div.parent().on("click", function() {
    // hide div when user clicks inside div's parent element
    $div.hide();
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
}
#divd {
  background: blue;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">click</a>

<div class="container">

  <div id="divd">this is the div</div>

</div>
```